# SwiftUI ForEach identify by \.self with duplicate values

Tags: swift, swiftui

[Solved by making in an in between type]

```
struct ColorType: Identifiable {
        
    var id = UUID()
    var color: Color
}
```

End of edit

I have an array with custom SwiftUI `Color`s which reside in the assets folder. Within a `View` a `Foreach` itterates through these values like this:

```
let colors: [Color] = [Color("InstrumentColor100"),Color("InstrumentColor100"),Color("InstrumentColor101")]

ForEach( colors, id: \.self) { color in
    Rectangle().fill(color)
}
```

This will serve me the runtime error:
ForEach<Array, Color, _ShapeView<Rectangle, Color>>: the ID NamedColor(name: "InstrumentColor100", bundle: nil) occurs multiple times within the collection, this will give undefined results!

I do understant this is due to id: .self not finding unique values to create unique ID's. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72811440/swiftui-foreach-explanation) stating to use `id: \.keyPath` but I do not have a keyPath rendering 3 aditional errors.

What would be a low overhead way to make these values (apear) unique?

BTW, the code works, but the console overflows wthe the sayd error.

Comment: Do you actually need to display the duplicate colors? If not, you could simply remove the duplicates by using a `Set`.

Comment: It's drawing in layers on the ZStack, in some combinations double names are possible. @Raja Kishan Not completely. The ideau to create a sctruct with id and string does not wotk with Color() which needs an initialiser value, which String doesn't

Answer (score 3):

you could try this simple approach:

```
ForEach(colors.indices, id: \.self) { index in  
       Rectangle().fill(colors[index]) 
}
```

Comment: I ended up not using .enumerated but creating an in between type with ID. like this: 
`import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ColorType: Identifiable {
        
    var id = UUID()
    var color: Color
}`

Comment: does my answer not work for you? No need for any mumbo jumbo.

Comment: Sorry, I added a comment to the wrong answer. I got it working before I read your answer

Answer (score 1):

One solution you can try is to derive an array with indices like this:

```
let foo = ["a", "b", "c"]
let bar = Array(foo.enumerated())
print(bar)
// [(offset: 0, element: "a"), (offset: 1, element: "b"), (offset: 2, element: "c")]
```

You now have an array with named tuples. Then you should be able to do:

```
ForEach(bar, \.offset) {
    tuple in
    Rectangle().fill(tuple.element)
}
```

Comment: This loook like a good solution. It seems it's still missing an argument label. When I run `let colorsArray = Array(colors.enumerated())
                                
                                ForEach( colorsArray, \.offset) { tupple in
                                    Rectangle().fill(tupple.element)
                                }` I get te error "Missing argument label 'id:' in call" on line with ForEach on it

Comment: Good to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59295206/how-do-you-use-enumerated-with-foreach-in-swiftui) against use of .enumerated